# How to use send responses back to ajax and process each response separately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

On Page1:
An AJAX script is processed loading Page2

On Page2:
A mysqli Database query will run, if the database query is successful, I want to send a success response back to AJAX query and reload the page.  If the database query fails, I want to send a fail response back to AJAX query and redirect to fail page.

Is this possible?  How would I write this?  I'm new to AJAX and have reviewed some AJAX scripts and also read documentation, but I learn best by experimenting with code to find solutions that work for me.  I have played with a few ajax scripts but can't get any of them to work correctly and can't find one that does anything near what I need.  Seems like it would be a fairly easy ajax script, so I was hoping someone could help me with it.

Comment: If the only two outcomes are "reload the page" and "redirect" then why use AJAX in the first place?  Just directing the user to Page 2 would allow you to then either direct the user back to Page 1 or to the Error Page.

Comment: one of my goals in this is learning AJAX.  I prob will go that route with live code, but this was also a way for me to kinda experiment with ajax some.  Seeing how the code works, and how to handle responses and how to generate responses

Comment: I was also in "tunnel vision" which is terrible.  I already had all this working and then tested in IE and there is an issue with what I was doing in IE with conflicting scripts and throwing errors and so I started thinking of a way to change my current code and ajax was the first thought of how to do it.  It hadn't even processed in my head to just move the code around and change how the links work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible jQuery solution.  Let me know if you want pure JavaScript.

index.html

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button type="button">Submit!</button>
```

scripts.js

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
    var val = $('#input').val();

    sendQuery(val);
});

function sendQuery(x) {
    var val = x;

    $('body').load('query.php?input=' + val);
}
```

query.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','db');

$val = $_GET['input'];

$query = <<<Q
         SELECT
         *

         FROM
         table

         WHERE
         column = ?
Q;

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$val);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
            #if the query is successful
            echo '<script>
                     $(function() {
                          location.reload();
                     });
                 </script>';
    }
} else {
        echo '<script>
                 $(function() {
                      window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com/errorpage.html";
                 });
             </script>';
}

$mysqli->close();
```

The only thing I'm uncertain about is why you want to send a response back with AJAX, and then move to a completely new page.  To me that kind of seems like that negates the reason you're wanting to use AJAX in the first place.  Any thoughts?

What the above does is use jQuery to load XMLHTTPRequest.responseText into the body (the reponseText is the scripts that are echoed by your php doc).  In this case, in the case of success from the db, it echoes a script that reloads the page.  In the case of a failure, it echoes a script that moves the user to an error page.

Comment: I know its not the right setup, but what is the difference between how yours looks and the way this one is set up.  http://jsfiddle.net/8BmQP/  I don't know much about AJAX and all this is a learning advantage for me.  I know the specific scenerio is kinda pointless, but this kinda teaches me how to work with AJAX a little to get started.

Comment: And what you are doing is loading the page into a div.  I don't want to load the page in at all.  I wanted all of this to be processed behind the scenes.  Am I missing something from your example?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "I want to send a fail/success response back to the AJAX query"?

Comment: Instead of $('#resulArea').load(), maybe $('body').load() could suit your purpose.  Then, in the PHP doc, just remove the echo "Error" and echo $res statements.  This way, only a script will be sent back to the original page based on a success or failure of your query.

Comment: The only thing page2 does is query and update database.  Now, if that fails., I wanted the page to be redirected to a failure page.  Or even back to the main page with an error message.  This is kinda something I can play with once I figure out how all of this works.  But, if the query is successful, I want to refresh page1.  But I never want the user to see themselves leaving page1.  I am new to all of this, so sorry if I said something that wasn't possible like sending a success/fail response.  I'm not sure exactly how AJAX/JSON gets a response at all.

Comment: I saw `success: function(data) ` and kinda saw that thought about... so do this on success do this on fail.  Just not sure the best practice of doing this.  And being page2 is in the background and not actually being seen by the user, so I wasn't sure if adding a code to redirect to error page on that page would be possible.

Comment: I would suggest reading [MDN's explanation of the AJAX stuff (aka the XMLHTTPRequest object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).  This will elaborate on how the AJAX stuff truly works, which may help you with what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: okay thanks.  I am going to accept your answer because you did provide code.  I will continue reading on information about your code and AJAX some more.  Thanks for the reference to the explanation.

Comment: No problem.  I would also suggest reading [the w3schools explanation of AJAX with pure JavaScript (the XMLHTTPRequest)](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp).  Please let me know if you have any other thoughts or questions.